# How to set cookiejar globally so that the cookies are present in every http.Client request

Tags: http, go, cookies, client

I am new here and a bit confused with setting cookie jar  gloabally. I am using cookiejar from the http package and this is my implementation from other docs available in setting the cookies as jar in http.Client.

```
    jar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := &http.Client{
      Jar: jar,
    }
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", request_url, nil)
    q := req.URL.Query()
    q.Add("authtoken", token)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    res, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close() 
    fmt.Println(res.Cookies()) // can see the cookies here
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to have this declared gloabally so that once the jar is set the subsequent client request will have the cookies.
If I place it in any other function it gets sets to nil again.

```
    jar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := &http.Client{
      Jar: jar,
    }
```

Any best practise available in how to do this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`http.Client`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) is designed to be reused:

> The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP connections), so **Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.**

So simply just create / configure an `http.Client`, and reuse it everywhere where you want your cookiejar to work.

If one configured `http.Client` doesn't fit all your use cases, then create as many clients that do. To ensure the same cookiejar is used, you may create a client "factory" function which ensures the returned `http.Client` will have the Jar set.

Answer (score 1):

Undoable (at least you cannot *force* the use of your client).

Nearest is injecting your client into net/http.DefaultClient.

Most sensible is to use icza's solution.